# Issues with collection of Dynamically typed service classes & objects

Tags: scala, reflection, types, playframework, casting

We are building data structure migration system that should be capable of migrating from any version of a case class to the latest one; as well as from the latest version to any one of the previous ones.
The concept is as follows:

We have a structure of case classes and migration classes

```
v1/SchemaV1 <= Case class V1
v2/SchemaV2 <= Case class V2
v2/MigrationV2 <= Migration Class from 1->2 and back
v3/SchemaV3 <= Case class V3
v3/MigrationV3 <= Migration Class from 2->3 and back
...
```

Where:

- case classes can potentially be anything, however they are implementing the same interface `Schema`
- Migration classes implement Migration trait and must implement 'up' and 'down' methods that simply convert one object into another.

Currently Migration trait looks like this:

```
trait TypedMigration[F <: Schema, T <: Schema] {

  type FromSchema = F
  type ToSchema = T

  /**
    * This method is responsible for migrating one version of a schema 'F'(From) to another 'T' (To)
    *
    * @param from
    * @return
    */
  def up(from: FromSchema): ToSchema

  /**
    * This method is responsible for migrating one version of a schema down one level
    *
    * @param from
    * @return
    */
  def down(from: ToSchema): FromSchema
}
```

The idea here, that every implementation of migration class will have `from` and `to` types enforced.

As an example:

```
class V2Migration extends TypedMigration[v1.SchemaV1, v2.SchemaV2] {
   ...
}
```

How, there is a service class the responsible for managing this whole migration process. This class has two methods that handles migrations 'up' & 'down' respectively

As an example:

```
protected[versioning] def doMigrateUp(schema: Schema): ChecklistSchema = {

    // load all required migration classes
    val migrations = loadMigrationObjects[Schema, Schema](resolveSchemaVersion(schema), targetVersion)

    var migratedSchema = schema
    // apply all migrations up
    migrations.foreach { migration =>
      migratedSchema = migration.up(migratedSchema)
    }

    migratedSchema.asInstanceOf[ChecklistSchema]
  }
```

Where:

- `loadMigrationObjects' method returns a list of migration objects in order
- `ChecklistSchema` is a type alias to the latest version. So I can safely cast to it at the end.

All good till now...

The problem for me begins in the 'doMigrateDown` method:

```
protected[versioning] def doMigrateDown[S <: Schema](schema: ChecklistSchema, targetVersion: Int): S = {
    val migrations = loadMigrationObjects[Schema, ChecklistSchema](resolveSchemaVersion(schema), targetVersion)

    var migratedSchema = schema
    // apply all migrations down
    migrations.foreach { migration =>
      migratedSchema = migration.down(migratedSchema)
    }

    migratedSchema.asInstanceOf[S]
  }
```

Here, there are two problems:

1. I am getting compilation error:
   [image]
2. I am not sure if this casting can actually work.

I this point I am totally stuck...

For the reference, this is how we build the list of migration objects:

```
protected[versioning] def loadMigrationObjects[F <: Schema, T <: Schema](currentVersion: Int, targetVersion: Int): List[TypedMigration[F, T]] = {

    val migrationsRange = if (currentVersion <= targetVersion) {
      currentVersion + 1 to targetVersion
    } else {
      currentVersion to targetVersion + 1 by -1
    }

    val migrations = List[TypedMigration[F, T]]()

    migrationsRange.foldLeft(migrations) { case (acc, versionNumber) =>
      Try {

        val migrationClassName = MigrationClassNameFormat.format(versionNumber, versionNumber)
        Class.forName(migrationClassName).newInstance().asInstanceOf[TypedMigration[F, T]]

      } match {
        case Success(m) => acc :+ m
        case Failure(e: ClassNotFoundException) =>
          logger.info("migration class was not found", e)
          acc
        case Failure(e) => throw e
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Try `migrations.foldRight(schema)({ case (mig, schema) => mig.up(schema)})`. Typecasting usually indicates there's a better way. It might also be possible to use implicit conversions to have the compiler assemble the schema conversions for you.

Comment: @Reactormonk Try it where, when I am applying migrations? Also, the up migration does not seem to be a problem. And your suggestion does not solve anything...

Comment: Could you show your `loadMigrationObjects`? From the code here, it seems like you're taking a good approach having the compiler verify the schemas for you and then throwing the type information away again.

Comment: @Reactormonk It is in the post. The last code in there.

Comment: I assume you want to have type safety and still be able to execute different migrations at runtime. Would you accept an approach using shapeless HLists? That would be the way to keep type safety and still be able to execute migrations from different versions. However, reflection and type safety don't mix very well, so you'll have to pick one.

Comment: Honestly speaking, at this point I would be happy with anything that is safe enough and works :) I am quite newby in scala world, so anything really is good for me, I can improve it later, if I have to.

Comment: @Reactormonk However, I am not sure what you mean by `shapeless HLists`.

Comment: I've been looking for db migration myself - would https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/sbt.html suit your requirements?

Comment: @Reactormonk This works for the case when you can migrate the entire database in one go. In our case, we have mongoDB with potentially huge number of docs and we are trying to build on the fly (lazy) migration.